# How to prove that this integral approaches $\pi$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$$I = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-\epsilon \sin(t)}e^{\epsilon i\cos(t)}dt$$

How to prove that the integral approaches $\pi$ as epsilon approaches zero? I applied jordan's lemma and got $\pi$ as upper bound, but the lower and upper bound should approach the same value (squeeze theorem).

Comment: Can't you just substitute $\epsilon=0$ and get $\int 1 dt=\pi$?

Answer (score 0):

Take $\epsilon_n>0$ such that $\epsilon_n \to 0$

Define $g_n(t)=e^{-\epsilon_n\sin{t}}e^{i\epsilon_n\cos{t}}$

Then $g_n(x) \to 1$ and $|g_n(x)| \leq 1 \in L^1[0,\pi]$ since $\sin{t} \geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$

So by dominated convergence you have the limit.

Comment: How does $g_n(x) \to 1$?

Comment: If you take $\epsilon_n \to 1$ then is goes to $1$. Note that the function $f(s)=e^{-s\sin{t}}e^{is\cos{t}}$ is continuous at $zero$